# JPA, Hibernate, Spring MVC, Maven - Definição

Tags: hibernate, jpa, maven, spring-mvc

Estou com muitas dúvidas em definições! Meu objetivo é construir uma arquitetura de um sistema, porém as definições de JPA, HIBERNATE, SPRING MVC, MAVEN, são obscuras.

**JPA:** Nada mais é que uma especificação  (ok)

**Hibernate:**  Provedor de Persistência, quem irá implementar as especificações da JPA.

**SPRING MVC:** Ele é um framework ORM? (Li em alguns lugares que sim).

**Maven:** Não sei.

Pensando em uma montagem de uma arquitetura, o que comunica com o que?

Answer (score 5):

boa noite, vamos esclarecer cada um desses pontos.

**JPA** - É o que você falou.

**Hibernate** - É o que você falou.

**Spring MVC** - Ele é um framework, porem não um ORM, no caso seu ORM seria o próprio hibernate, o Spring MVC atua na camada Web da sua aplicação ele vai ser o responsável por gerenciar toda a camada de controladores da sua aplicação, ira prover facilidades comuns de frameworks MVC como databinds para as classes da sua aplicação, tratar aspectos do protocolo http, expor endpoints da sua aplicação entre outras coisas mais, outra coisa muito importante a ser dita é que o Spring MVC não trabalha sozinho, tudo gira em torno do core do Spring que é um container de Beans da sua aplicação, e isso vai lhe proporcionar muitas funcionalidades, é meio difícil entrar em detalhes muitos detalhes sobre isso, isso por si só seria um post a parte, mas vou colocar algumas referencias para você poder obter mais informações.

**Maven** Sua ferramente da build, com ele você pode fazer diversas tarefas, desde gerenciar o ciclo de vida da sua aplicação, através de "goals", você também pode gerenciar dependências da sua aplicação e usar plugins para atender necessidades especificas da sua aplicação, vamos supor por exemplo que ao rodar uma goal que é provida por um plugin, você gostaria de fazer deploy da sua aplicação em um servidor do tomcat, o MAVEN possui plugins que tem essas funcionalidades.

### Uma imagem muito interessante de como o está disposta a arquitetura dos projetos do Spring.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**REFERENCIAS**

- http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/overview.html
- http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html
- https://maven.apache.org/

Espero ter ajudado, qualquer coisa pode perguntar eu respondo nos comentários o resto.